# Spacy model inconsistent prediction

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have trained a spacy model on below sentences.

```
sent1 - STREET abc city: pqr COUNTY: STATE: qw ziP: 99999
```

```
sent2 - STREET qwe city: ewwe COUNTY: STATE: we ziP: 99990
```

I have annotated as shown below:

```
risk_street_label   STREET
risk_street_value   abc
risk_city_label     city
risk_city_value     pqr 
risk_state_label    STATE
risk_state_value    qw
risk_zip_label      ziP
risk_zip_value      99999
```

Have a training set of around 50 sentences. Containing different values but the label and the order is same.

For similar sentences the prediction is proper.

But while taking prediction for random sentences also it is predicting the classes.

For e.g. - Ram is a great

Prediction:

```
risk_street_value   Ram is a great
```

I have also trained Watson Knowledge Studio and there it is predicting fine.
Below is an example of Watson Prediction:

```
RiskStreetLabel STREET  RiskStreetValue abc 
RiskCityLabel   city    RiskCityValue   pqr 
RiskStateLabel  STATE   RiskStateValue  qw  
RiskZipLabel    ziP RiskZipValue    12345
```

Can someone please help me as in where I am going wrong?

Below is the spacy standard code:

```
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    sizes = util.decaying(0.6, 0.2, 1e-4)
    for itn in range(iterations):
        print("Statring iteration " + str(itn))
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        losses = {}
        for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
            nlp.update(
                [text],  # batch of texts
                [annotations],  # batch of annotations
                drop=0.5,  # dropout - make it harder to memorise data
                sgd=optimizer,  # callable to update weights
                losses=losses)
        print(losses)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach. I'll point some and you can research deeper:

**Dataset size**: 50 sentences is too small for a machine learning based approach. What spacy does is: it trains a machine learning model that takes into account word POS and surrounding words POS, vectors, etc. This, in turn, requires a lot of examples for the algorithm to properly 'infer' some of the informations.

**Your data is not "Natural Language"**: What I mean is that you have structured data and you want to generalize from it. Natural Language models learn from the context (surrounding words) and you are providing a unnatural, structured context to all training samples. You won't be able to generalize from this, since your samples are not general enought.

In summary: gather more diverse data.

Comment: Thanks Tiago, Can you suggest what should I use for my use-case in particular?

Comment: If your data is all structured like above, you could simply use some Regex. Or even a simple "string".split(":") could work to separate the fields (looks like ':' is the separator).